# Android ListView Jump to cursor position

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that is controlled by a standard BaseAdapter.

When the user clicks a button, I want the ListView to Scroll into view the 100th record.

How is that done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this function

> public void setSelection (int position)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Sets the currently
>   selected item. If in touch mode, the
>   item will not be selected but it will
>   still be positioned appropriately. If
>   the specified selection position is
>   less than 0, then the item at position
>   0 will be selected. Parameters
>   position  Index (starting at 0) of the
>   data item to be selected.

So `myListView.setSelection(99);`